# Express req.protocol always returns https

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https

I have an server running express. It uses req.protocol to force https. However, when I visit the site on http, it still give https.

Here is the function:

```
 app.use((req, res, next)=>{
        console.log(req.protocol);
        if(req.protocol === "https"){
            next();
        }else{
            res.redirect(`https://${req.headers.host}${req.url}`);
        }
    });
```

It isn't redirecting and therefore the site isn't working. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What does that `console.log` output? What does your browser's network tab shows? what response does you get?

Comment: `console.log` shows https. Network tabl just shows status failed. I get "This page isn't working", site didn't send any data.  The site works perfectly on https. Only when I specifically use http does it not work.

Comment: @LeeMorgan - Are you sure your server is even responding to HTTP? Are you opening two ports? Remember you serve HTTP and HTTPS on separate ports (80 and 443, by default). From your description, it sounds like you're only serving HTTPS. For instance, see [the `listen` docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.listen) and how they're calling `listen` twice in their HTTP+HTTPS example. Are you doing that?

Comment: Yep, you were exactly right. Usually I use an if statement to run on 443 if it is production, then run on 80 right after that. This time I used an if/else statement that was stopping port 80 in production. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad I guessed right! I can post it as an answer if you think it'll help others in the future, or you can delete the question if you prefer. Happy coding either way!

Comment: Ya, you saved me, I was in panic mode haha. Post an answer and I'll accept it. It might help if someone makes that stupid mistake as well. All I could find were answers for why it is always http, not the other way around. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your server is only responding to HTTPS requests, not HTTP requests. Remember you serve HTTP and HTTPS on separate ports (80 and 443, by default). From your description, it sounds like you're only serving HTTPS. Here's the example from the [Express `listen` docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.listen) for how they serve both:

```
var express = require('express')
var https = require('https')
var http = require('http')
var app = express()

http.createServer(app).listen(80)
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443)
```

Note that they called `listen` twice, once each on two different servers, one for HTTP and another for HTTPS.